# Type 'String?' has no member 'default'とエラーが出る

Tags: swift

```
let action = UIAlertController(title: "OK", message: .default) {(_)in
```

書くと `Type 'String?' has no member 'default'` というエラーが出ます。　なぜこのようなエラーが出るのでしょうか？どう直せばエラーが消えますか？

Comment: 何かのサイトか参考書籍からコードを手入力で引き写されたのでしょうか?`UIAlertController(title: "OK", message: .default)`ではなく、`UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)`ではありませんか?

Comment: 参考書籍を使って練習をしてました。問題治りました！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

エラーが出る理由を補足します。

引数のmessageはString?型の値です。
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller/1620106-message

そのため、コンパイラはStringが省略されたものとして以下のように解釈します。

```
UIAlertController(title: "OK", message: String.default)
```

ですが、String型にはdefaultという名前のプロパティ（メンバ変数）は存在しないため、
「String?型はdefaultというメンバ変数を持ちません」というエラーが出ます。

```
type 'String?' has no member 'default'
```